# Dynamic Paint and PBR

Tags: particles, color, pbr

[image]

I'm trying to create a dumbbell coloring scene. Initially, the dumbbell has a simple **PBR** material.

[image]

When adding the '*Attribute*' node, the dumbbell loses its color.

[image]

When adding a “*Mix Color*” node between “*Attribute*” and “*Principled BSDF*”, the spray paint fades. Is there a way to preserve the material of the dumbbell and the paint color on it? Blender version 3.6.2.

Comment: Disable "Dry" feature under Canvas properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use this shader setup, to preserve the material:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot!