# Dynamic Paint vs Run Away Paint

Tags: particles, color, pbr

I'm running a *Render Animation* on a dumbbell painting scene ([*Related Question*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301596/dynamic-paint-and-pbr)). I'm using a standard scheme to simulate **Dynamic Paint** and **Particle System**. This scheme is described by some **YouTube** bloggers.

As you can see in the final video ([*Multifunctional Bottle-Dumbbell*](https://youtube.com/shorts/iGLdupbnQcw?feature=share)), some of the frames are losing color on the dumbbells. Because of this, the video is jerky.

For what reason could this be happening? Is it due to a weak **CPU** (*Intel* i5 8400) or is this a feature of **Dynamic Paint**?

**Blender** version 3.6.2.

Comment: What is the format used to store Canvas result - baked vertex cache or image sequence? Does it happening randomly, does it happening also in a default scene? Probably would by faster to share your simplified blend file to let us check.

Comment: Here is a link to the entire project file. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=eelsKGBW" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/eelsKGBW/)

Comment: Sorry, hard to solve your issue. Your file (you provided in comment above) does not contains any object set as DP Canvas ... BTW if you solved your issue [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301596/dynamic-paint-and-pbr) consider delete this Q. Thank you keep this site organised.